# Does, new npm packages able to update remotely with code-push-react-native?

Tags: react-native, code-push

I released one apk from PlayStore. Now I want some updates couple of screens. This changes required to use some new libraries. With this new library I'll achieved my requirements. Now I want to update remotely with manual release, using react-native-code-push. Is this possible? I know the appcenter only updates bundle file. But I didn't made any changes in native folder.If there anyway?

Comment: Can you confirm by using code push it updates npm package also which you updated or our react native JS code only @Elango ?

Answer (score 0):

If the new npm package you are using contains native code then no, those changes will not go through using code-push. Only JS changes are going to go through.

You can create a local build with some build version that you'll never use and give a code push to that particular version and test it.